# value of infinite product in expression

Tags: limits

> Find the value of the following expression  $$ \prod^{\infty}_{n=0}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{3n}}+\frac{1}{2^{6n}}\right)$$

What I tried:

If $\frac{1}{2^3}=x$, then we can write expression as

$$\prod^{\infty}_{n=0}(1-x^n+x^{2n})=(1-1+1)(1-x+x^2)(1-x^2+x^4)(1-x^3+x^6)\cdots$$

How do I find that infinite product

Comment: Use distributive law and show by induction, what $\prod_{n=0}^k$ equals for all arbitrary $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then take the limit. It should be 1, I guess.

Comment: There is no closed form in terms of usual constants and functions. If you allow theta functions and their friends then there is a closed form (see the answer by Nikos Bagis). If on the other hand $x=\exp(-\pi\sqrt{r}), r>0,r\in\mathbb {Q} $ then in principle one can get a closed using elementary functions and Gamma function values at rational numbers. And even this case is easily said than done unless one has Ramanujan type powers of algebraic manipulation.

Answer (score 4):

Almost all known information about the infinite product 
$\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1-x^k+x^{2k})$ is found at the [Online Encylopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/A109389), sequence A109389.

For example: Expansion of $\displaystyle \frac{q^{-1/12}\eta(q)\eta(q^6)}{\eta(q^2)\eta(q^3)}$ in powers of $q$.  Here, $\eta$ is the Dedekind eta function.

I suppose an expert could tell if that eta-quotient is Hauptmodul for a certain subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$, and then if $q=1/8$ turns out to be a cusp of the fundamental domain, we could evaluate this at $q=1/8$.

---

[This is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Sato_series#Modular_functions)
$$
j_{6B}(\tau) = \left(\frac{\eta(\tau)\eta(6\tau)}{\eta(2\tau)\eta(3\tau)}\right)^{-12}
$$
where $q=e^{2\pi i\tau}$.  If $q=1/8$ then $\tau = i(3\log 2)/(2\pi)$.  The known special values have $\tau$ algebraic, so this does not work.

Comment: The product can be evaluated only where $\tau$ is algebraic of degree 2 and with positive imaginary part. +1 already there.

Comment: "can be evaluated" -> "evaluation is known"

Answer (score 3):

*This is not an answer but just the result from a CAS.*

Using Pochhammer symbols, the infinite product corresponds to
$$L=\lim_{p\to \infty } \, 2^{-3 p (p+1)} \left(\frac{1-i \sqrt{3}}{2} ;8\right)_{p+1}
   \left(\frac{1+i \sqrt{3}}{2} ;8\right)_{p+1}$$
What is really amazing (at least to me) is the approximation
$$L=64\, \sqrt[31] {2\times 3^{10}\times e^{74}\times \log ^{759}(2)\times \log ^{632}(3)}$$ which is correct for $18$ significant figures.

Comment: How did you manage to come up with that approximation? It looks a bit frightening. +1

Answer (score 2):

We will use (see [3]): If $q=e^{-\pi\sqrt{r}}$, $r>0$, $k^{*}_r=\sqrt{1-k_r^2}$:
$$
\prod^{\infty}_{n=1}(1+q^n)=q^{-1/24}2^{-1/6}\left(\frac{k_r}{(k^{*}_r)^2}\right)^{1/12}.
$$
Hence if
$$
P=\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1-q^{n}+q^{2n}\right),\tag 1
$$
we have
$$
P^{12}=\left(\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1+q^{3n})}{(1+q^n)}\right)^{12}=q^{-1}\frac{k_{9r}}{k_r}\left(\frac{k^{*}_{r}}{k^{*}_{9r}}\right)^2.
$$
Hence in view of [1] pg.229-238 with $\alpha=k_r^2$, $\beta=k_{9r}^2$ and 
$$
m=\frac{_{2}F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;k_{9r}^2\right)}{{}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;k_r^2\right)}=\frac{z_9}{z_1},
$$
instead of $m=\frac{z_1}{z_9}$, we have 
$$
P=\sqrt[12]{8\frac{(1-3m)^2(1-m) m}{(1+m)^2(1+3m)}}.\tag 2
$$
The $m$ is the solution of ([2] chapter 5):
$$
27m^4-18m^2-8(1-2k^2)m-1=0\tag 3
$$
and 
$$
k=k_r=\left(\frac{\vartheta_2(0;1/8)}{\vartheta_3(0;1/8)}\right)^2\textrm{, }r=9\log^2(2)/\pi^2.\tag 4
$$
The theta functions are
$$
\vartheta_2(0,q):=\theta_2(q)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty}q^{(n+1/2)^2}\textrm{, }\vartheta_3(0,q):=\theta_3(q)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty}q^{n^2}.
$$

REFERENCES.

[1]: B.C. Berndt, 'Ramanujan`s Notebooks Part III'. Springer Verlang, New York (1991)

[2]: J.M. Borwein and P.B. Borwein. 'Pi and the AGM: A Study in Analytic Number Theory and Computational Complexity', Wiley, New York, 1987.

[3]: E.T.Whittaker and G.N.Watson, 'A course on Modern Analysis'. Cambridge U.P. (1927)